# building up an array of related data from divs

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I need to loop through divs and their children and obtain data values to be accessed in an array. I can console log all the information correctly via index and each looping the children but I can't get it correctly into an array whereby each block is indexed, then another each loop gets the children within that block and pulls the data attributes from each of those .inner divs.

Currently I do get an index of all the .block divs as arrays but within each of these rather than the 3 sets of data attributes (i.e as in the first .block having three .inner divs) it only pulls in the last set - e.g 7,56 whereas I need it to pull in 1,43 3,34 7,56

here is my html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="inner" data-a='1' data-b="43"></div>
        <div class="inner" data-a="3" data-b="34"></div>
        <div class="inner" data-a="7" data-b="56"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="inner" data-a='3' data-b="76"></div>
        <div class="inner" data-a="9" data-b="67"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="inner" data-a='5' data-b="33"></div>
        <div class="inner" data-a="4" data-b="22"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
frame  = $('.block');
blockNo = [];

frame.each(function( index ) {
    blockNo.push(index);
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        cell = $(this);
        blockNo[index] = [cell.data('a'),cell.data('b')];
    });      
});
```

Comment: I think your `index` vars may be getting mixed up, so you will always be overwriting 0 and 1

Comment: I suggest you use 2D array or JSON to store data instead of current array.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
blockNo.push(index);
```

you build an array of the index numbers.
Just use

```
blockNo.push([cell.data('a'),cell.data('b')]);
```

inside the `each` method.

Comment: I tried that within the children loop and getting a slightly different result, still returns only one childs data-attributes but apart from the last one (7,56) it's returning the first (1,43)

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem is in

```
blockNo[index] = [cell.data('a'),cell.data('b')];
```

Each iteration of child elements of the div.block you are doing blockNo[index], which keeps replacing the old value and so you are getting only the third set.

This should work

```
frame  = $('.block');
blockNo = [];

frame.each(function( index ) {

 $(this).children().each(function() {
    cell = $(this);
    blockNo.push([cell.data('a'),cell.data('b')])
 });      
});
```

Comment: Many thanks the suggestion above sorted it but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You have to build up each "row" element separately:

```
var frame = $('.block');
var blockNo = [];

frame.each(function( index ) {
    // a new array ("row") for each .block element
    var row = [];

    // fill it up with values
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        row.push([this.getAttribute("data-a"), this.getAttribute("data-b")]);
    });

    // add it to blockNo
    blockNo.push(row);
});
```

I also made `frame` and `blockNo` local variables (which is what one almost always wants) and replaced the calls to `.data` with straight DOM `getAttribute`. If you are not planning on accessing this information with `.data` in general then it's more efficient to not involve jQuery's data storage facility at all.

Comment: Brilliant this did it! I knew what I had to do I just couldn't quite figure it out thank you so much for the quick response Jon

Answer (score 0):

Using `.map()` and `.get()`:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dSvpA/)

```
var blocksArray = $('.block').find('.inner').map(function(){
    return [[$(this).data('a'),$(this).data('b')]];
}).get();
```

Comment: ahhhh I looked at .map() and .get() before I'll have a play now. Thanks!